# How to measure the terminal conversion rate of a population using Bayesian updating

Tags: bayesian, pymc

I have a time-lagged, multi-step conversion funnel. For simplicity, lets assume it looks like this:

```
Lead submit ----> Lead contact ----> Lead convert
```

Where each "arrow" can be represented by a Poisson distribution (for time to event) and a beta-binomial (for the conversion rate). I am attempting to use PyMC3 to measure this process.

At some point, I will know the conversion rate at a particular step for the population (a given cohort of lead submits) precisely. Therefore, I would want my posterior to no longer be a distribution of my expectation for the conversion rate, but rather be a single value since that rate is known. The later steps would still be a distribution since they haven't been fully realized yet.

How do I get that result? Currently, my functions return a distribution even when the cohort is complete. Am I thinking about this problem correctly?